# Rails - assets not found after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, assets

I'm trying to deploy my first Rails application, but I'm getting 404 Not found for all assets (.css, .js files and images). I tried many ways of getting things work, but nothing worked. All of the asset paths look like this:

```
/stylesheets/application.css
```

My production.rb file: http://pastebin.com/SeVNEZD9
My application.html.erb, where I include these assets look like this: http://pastebin.com/gHkpfA8Z
Thanks forward for any help.

Comment: which rails version you are using?

Comment: Using Rails version 4.0.4.

Comment: have you added code in `application.css`?? and are you using any web server?

Comment: see view page source and see url ??

Comment: Of course, my application.css is not empty. The links in the generated code are in this format: href="/stylesheets/application.css". Actually, I took a look into the /public/assets/ folder and there are files like these: 
application-92ae2c47126875c1c736990edf73a803.css
application-92ae2c47126875c1c736990edf73a803.css.gz

Comment: Have you used `stylesheet_tag` only right?

Comment: This is the way I include the assets in my layout files:
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/environments/production.rb` file add

```
 config.assets.digest = true
```

Then `stylesheet_link_tag` will generate fingerprints url.

Comment: It's been there, but it doesn't generate fingeprint url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to precompile your assets for this by running this command on terminal.

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: As I replied to the previous answer, I tried this, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

After deployment you should do

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: @gabriel please check these lines are there in environments/production.rb. http://pastie.org/9103118

Comment: Actually, you say that the `config.assets.compile` should be set to `false`, but in my code it's set to `true`. Which one is correct? (I tried to change it to `false` but it didn't help.

Comment: @gabriel That should be false. and do one more thing please comment the line config.serve_static_assets = false

Comment: @gabriel U restarted the service no? if you dont mind, can I have the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your first Rails app, let me explain where your problem might be:

> When you create your assets, they reside in the `asset pipeline`. This
>   is a folder located at `/app/assets` where your asset files will be
>   stored
>
> If you want to use assets in production, there are two ways to do it -
>   the first is to use the assets dynamically, or to use them as static
>   (which is where you precompile). When you use the likes of Heroku etc,
>   you need to use static assets, which is why they precompile them for
>   you when you deploy
>
> The problem with static assets is that Rails [creates fingerprints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)
>   for them. These fingerprints basically give them a unique identifier
>   which you have to dynamically reference using `<%= asset_path %>` etc

Your problem is likely caused by you not accessing the precompiled assets correctly. The way to fix this is to use [asset tag helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) like this:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= javascriot_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Actually, this is how my application.html.erb file looks like: http://pastebin.com/gHkpfA8Z

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's working now. I needed to restart the server to apply the changes. Can anybody tell me why is it that I have to restart the server to apply such changes? I want to avoid it in the future.

I'm posting my production.rb file for those who face similar problems: http://pastebin.com/7Uskvcuc

Comment: if are working in production means you have to restart the server,otherwise whatever changes you doing it'll not apply,it will take from cache.my answer is working means up-vote or accept my answer.